# Querying latest snapshot partition with Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, presto

I have a partitioned table with daily snapshots from from glue. When I use athena to query it queries across all partitions. Is there a way to get Athena to automatically only get the latest snapshot? Or do I have to explicitly state what partition I want to query if I want to avoid querying across all snapshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created tables as Hudi tables then you can use Athena to run Snapshot queries. For more please refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-hudi.html) link.

If the tables are directly created in Glue catalog then you have to explicitly mention the partition that you want to query.If you have a table with large number of partitions then try partition projection which is well explained in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html) link.